# Error while installing net-snmp in an openwrt environment

Tags: makefile, openwrt, net-snmp

I am trying to install net-snmp in an openwrt environment using the make from the link

​https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/net-snmp/Makefile?rev=25486

but when I run the makefile it throws the following error

install: cannot stat './files/snmpd.conf': No such file or directory

I don't understand, do I need to create the snmpd.conf file manually(if yes,in what location) or the makefile will automatically generate it(if yes, why is it not).

Comment: Did you checkout the entire `net-snmp` directory or just that one Makefile?

Comment: That's the problem. You didn't checkout the files it expects to work with. `files/snmpd.conf` is part of the source. You need it all.

Comment: I didnot find the entire net-snmp directory for openwrt, can you please refer me to some link from where i can download it?

Comment: just dawned upon me what you were trying to say, worked like a charm.Thank you @EtanReisner